# Unable to access websites

Tags: firefox, internet, internet-explorer, blocking

Recently I have had some problems accessing websites. When I try to access them it says:

> This webpage is not available.

I tried accessing the site through Firefox, Internet Explorer and Chrome. I also tried using a web proxy but I still have the same problem. This problem is only on my desktop PC; all the websites work fine on my laptop.

Currently, I cant access `yahoo.com`, `download.com`, `bing.com`, `proxy.org`, `daniweb.com` `aol.com`, and many forums.

I checked with the host file, but nothing is blocked in that. Can someone please suggest what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Could it be that your cat has pulled the network cable from the back of your PC? Anyhow, I am nominating your question for migration to http://superuser.com where you are more likely to find a solution :)

Comment: Check the DNS settings on the network connection.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, are all sites unavailable, or just some?
If only a few sites are unavailable, the problem may be at their end.

If all web-sites have a problem, then you have to consider that your browser needs to look up the IP address of the site first, looking up the name from a DNS server. If there's no DNS server available, the lookup will fail.

Start with the basics.
Start a **Command Prompt** (Start > Run > cmd.exe) and try to ping one of the problem web-sites:

```
ping www.sitename.com
```

If the **ping** command reports something like:

```
Ping request could not find host ...
```

...then you may fairly low-level network problem.

If however the ping command reports replies from some remote system, that proves your network connection and DNS look-ups are working OK.

So the next thing to check would be network/proxy settings. These can be (mis-)configured in your browser, but since you say all browsers are affected in the same way, it could be a Windows setting.

Answer (score -1):

Check firewalls/virusscan/routers/connectioncable/dns settings etc.. maybe some newly installed software blocking the connection?